# In VS2010: keyboard shortcut schema "Default" vs "Visual C# 2005"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, schema, shortcut

In VS2010, would it be better to use the Default keyboard shortcut schema instead of the Visual C# 2005 one?  Is the "Visual C# 2005" keyboard shortcut schema deprecated ?  Why is it called Visual C# 2005 and not Visual C# 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your practice how you use. If you work on multiple languages use default keyboard. I prefer C#.